# Extracting Zip From HTTP Response in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, https

I'm able to get the zip from HTTPs response and store in a specific folder  using below code snippet:

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(statement_resp.content))
z.extractall("/pathtostore")
```

However, in `/pathtostore` the **zip file gets extracted with some random name**. Is there a way to control the name of zip files created while extracting itself?

Currently, after zip extraction, below is the directory structure:

> /pathtostore/ZaXyzzz

--> ZaXyzzz is the zip name.

I'm looking for something as below:

> /pathtostore/1234_2020_03_02

--> 1234_2020_03_02 (cid_curdate) is the zip name which I want.

PS: I cannot read the zip and rename it as there could be multiple zip present inside `/pathtostore`

Comment: `data = zip.read(old_name)` and  `fh = open(new_name, 'w')` `fh.write()` `fh.close()` ?

Comment: @furas: I do not know the name of zip when it gets extracted. As there could be multiple zip directories inside /pathtostore, how will read the specific zip dir?

Comment: maybe first you should read documentation [zip.namelist()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist)

Comment: BTW: in [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/zipfile.py#L1632) you can even see `extractall()` uses `namelist()`

Answer (score 0):

You can get names `z.namelist()` and read every file separatelly `z.read()` and write it with new name using standarad `open()`, `write()`, `close()`

Minimal example.

It may need more code if zipfile has folders

```
import zipfile
import datetime
import os

z = zipfile.ZipFile('input.zip')

folder = '/pathtostore'
os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)

today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y_%m_%d')
cid = 0

for old_name in z.namelist():

    cid += 1
    new_name = os.path.join(folder, '{:04}_{}'.format(cid, today))

    print(old_name, '->', new_name)

    data = z.read(old_name)

    with open(new_name, 'wb') as fh:
        fh.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the zipfile's ZipInfo structures and modify its `filename` attribute for the write

```
from pathlib import Path

z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(statement_resp.content))
for info in z.getinfo():
    # implement your extraction policy here. Remove root
    # path name and add our own
    zip_path = Path(z.filename)
    z.filename = str(Path("1234_2020_03_02").joinpath(*zip_path.parts[1:]))
    x.extract(info)
```